# Showing wrong calculated value when filter applied in the Grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

We defined an ag-grid that has three columns show last_year sales, current_year sales, and another column showing the percentage % difference between last_year sales & current_year sales and its group by customer name.

The issue is the column of percentage % difference shows correctly if NO filter applies to the grid, but once we filter on a specific customer, the percentage % difference value is calculated wrong for some reason.

Does anyone know why and how to fix that?

Thanks,

I expected the calculation of the percentage % diff value should be correct regarding what filter applies or not.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and found that I was missing an `aggFunc: "sum"` in my column definition of the calculated column. Hope that helps.